# Has anyone tried google managed prometheus with TLS on their applications

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-managed-prometheus

I am wondering if anyone has tried google managed prometheus with TLS enabled on their applications that are running on GKE.

I am trying to configure my app with TLS to be successfully monitored using Google managed prometheus, but the web lacks the support and documentation specific to google managed prometheus and TLS using Podmonitoring in [Google managed prometheus repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/tree/v0.8.2)

Comment: What are the errors did you get when scraping application metrics?

Comment: IIUC it's not possible to auth scrapes see this (somewhat long-standing) [issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/issues/238) and the absence of `TLSConfig` or similar in [`PodMonitoringSpec`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/blob/v0.8.2/doc/api.md#podmonitoringspec)

Comment: I think it's waiting https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/prometheus-engine/pull/776

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from comments above, the feature is pending.